# Insertar valores en base de datos mediante php

Tags: php, mariadb

Me da un error a la hora de insertar unos valores en la base de datos. Llevo ya un rato mirando y no acierto con el error. Éste es mi código:

Formulario HTML:

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
                            <fieldset class="fieldset">
                                <legend>Introduce los datos de tu evento:</legend>
                                <input class="inputForm1" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre del Evento..." required>
                                <input class="inputForm1" type="text" name="lugar" placeholder="Lugar..." required>
                                <input class="inputForm1" type="text" name="descripcion" placeholder="Descripción..." required>
                                <input class="inputForm1" type="number" name="precio" placeholder="Precio..." required>
                                <input class="inputForm1" type="number" name="plazas" placeholder="Plazas..." required>
                                <input class="inputForm1" type="date" name="fecha" placeholder="Fecha..." required>
                                <input class="inputForm1" type="time" name="hora" placeholder="Hora..." required>
                                <input type="submit" value="Crear Evento" class="btnForm"/> 
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
```

Código PHP que recibe el `form` que se encuentra en el mismo archivo:

```css
 require '../php/eventos.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

     if (isset($_POST['nombre'])) {

        // Obtener parámetro idalumno
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $lugar = $_POST['lugar'];
        $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
        $precio = $_POST['precio'];
        $plazas = $_POST['plazas'];
        $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
        $hora = $_POST['hora'];
        //$idUsuario = $_POST['idUsuario'];
         
         function cambiaf_a_mysql($fecha){
            ereg( "([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{2,4})", $fecha, $mifecha);
            $lafecha=$mifecha[3]."-".$mifecha[2]."-".$mifecha[1];
            return $lafecha;
        }
    


        // Tratar retorno
        $retorno = Eventos::insertWeb($nombre,$lugar,$descripcion,$precio,$plazas,$fecha,$hora);


        if ($retorno) {

            //$alumno["estado"] = 1;        // cambio "1" a 1 porque no coge bien la cadena.
           // $alumno["alumno"] = $retorno;
            // Enviar objeto json del alumno
            //print json_encode($retorno);
            header('Location: actividades.php');
        } else {
            // Enviar respuesta de error general
            print json_encode(
                array(
                    'estado' => '2',
                    'mensaje' => 'No se obtuvo el registro'
                )
            );
        }

    } else {
        // Enviar respuesta de error
        print json_encode(
            array(
                'estado' => '3',
                'mensaje' => 'Se necesita un identificador'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Código PHP que inserta en la BD, se encuentra en eventos.php:

```css
public static function insertWeb($nombre,$lugar,$descripcion,$precio,$plazas,$fecha,$hora) {
        // Sentencia INSERT
        $comando = "INSERT INTO evento ( " ."nombre," ."lugar,"  ."descripcion," ."precio," ."plazas," ."fecha," ."hora" . " VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        // Preparar la sentencia
        $sentencia = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($comando);

        return $sentencia->execute(array($nombre,$lugar,$descripcion,$precio,$plazas,$fecha,$hora));

    }
```

Y el error que muestra:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES( 'a','a','a','1','1','2016-06-09','00:00')' at line 1' in .../php/eventos.php:161 Stack trace: #0 /home/u695092214/public_html/php/eventos.php(161): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 .../vistas/crearEvento.php(150): Eventos::insertWeb('a', 'a', 'a', '1', '1', '2016-06-09', '00:00') #2 {main} thrown in .../php/eventos.php on line 161

Comment: Yo utilizo una librería helper para interectuar con mysqli, es la mysqli database https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en cómo generas la sentencia de inserción: **te falta un cierre de paréntesis al final de la lista de campos**. Ahora mismo tienes (lo divido en diferentes líneas para que se vea bien):

```
$comando = "INSERT INTO evento ( " .
                "nombre," ."lugar,"  ."descripcion," ."precio," .
                "plazas," ."fecha," ."hora" . 
           " VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Sólo tienes que cerrar el paréntesis después del campo `hora`:

```
$comando = "INSERT INTO evento ( " .
                "nombre," ."lugar,"  ."descripcion," ."precio," .
                "plazas," ."fecha," ."hora   )" . 
           " VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias era eso y no lo veia.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puede ser porque no le introduces en los campos de VALUES, los textos encerrados en comillas, los números no necesitas.

También comprueba el formato de la fecha en la base de datos, el mínimo error de coincidencia hará que falle.

Si podrías copiar el código en vez de las capturas me facilitarías leer tu código. =D

Un saludo.

Comment: ya lo he modificado espero que asi lo leas mejor

Comment: Las comillas no son el problema. MySQL interpreta y convierte los valores automáticamente; por ejemplo, `'1'` se convierte en `1`. Si hablamos de manera estricta, no hace falta poner comillas en los campos numéricos, pero tampoco van a causar el error que menciona OP.

Comment: Vale, lo acabo de probar y tienes razón. Gracias ahora borro el comentario.